# Unit testing seems to use old data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, unit-testing, moq

Currently I'am trying to create a unit test for my project.

> ```
>     [TestMethod]
>     public void CustomerCreateEdit()
>     {
>         //Create Customer
>         customer = new Customer();
>         customer.Name = "customerBeforeEdit";
>         controller.Create(customer);
>         Assert.AreEqual(customer.Name, customerRepository.GetById(customer.Id).Name, "Customer Added");
>
>         //Edit Customer
>         customer.Name = "customerAfterEdit";
>         var fakeForm = new FormCollection();
>         fakeForm.Add("Name", customer.Name);
>         controller.ValueProvider = fakeForm.ToValueProvider();
>         controller.Edit(customer);
>         Customer actual = customerRepository.GetById(customer.Id);
>         Assert.AreEqual(customer.Name, actual.Name, "Customer Edited");
>
>     }
> ```

This unit test fails though...
The create part goes fine but at last line of the unit test it fails.
The thing is, if I add a breakpoint to the last line and hover over '**actual**' (second line from the bottem) It will say that the name of that customer is '**customerBeforeEdit**', but if i check in my database while that breakpoint is active it will actually be '**customerAfterEdit**'. So for some reason the test method will use the old values of the database. Does anyone know why this is,  and how i can resolve it?

Thanks, Vince

Comment: Side note: Unit tests not supposed to use data from database, if code under test reads/writes to DB such tests often called "integration" tests (as next level of tests after unit-tests).

Comment: You appear to be using a separate `customerRepository` in your unit test to verify the data, and presumably the `controller` being tested has its own separate repository instance. As a result, the test repository is unaware of the changes made to customer by the controller, hence the possibility of a stale cache. Would suggest you create a new repository before each fetch in your test (or use a different data access technique, e.g. simple ADO). To confirm Alexei's observation - testing the whole stack like this is called Integration testing.

Comment: You might be right with that, i think i need to set the customerRepository of my controller. And thanks about saying it's actually an integration test